# Automatically activating conda environment in integrated terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have an anaconda virtual environment that I wish to use. I am able to use `Select Interpreter`, which finds and allows me to accurately select said virtual environment. I am also able to use this with jupyter notebooks. What I am not able to do is have the integrated terminal automatically activate this environment.

Every time I open a new terminal, I have:

```
(base) PS C:\working_folder
```

If I manually activate the environment in the integrated terminal, I am then able to use it. My issue is that I don't want to have to remember to manually activate it.

Things I've tried:

- Setting `"Python.terminal.activateEnvironment"` to `true`
- Setting `"Python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal"` to `true`
- Updating `pythonPath` in my working folder `settings.json`

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been resolved?

Comment: Yes, thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Powershell and **run as Administrator**, execute the following command

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```

Then restart VS Code, add the following in **User Settings.json**:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "\\path\\to\\conda\\python.exe",
"Python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
"Python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true
```

**Reload Window** from Command Palette, select `base:conda` as python interpreter then press **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new integrated Terminal, conda environment should be activated automatically in it.